# mysql selecting rows from related tables with id

Tags: mysql

Roles table

```
id | role_name
----------------------
1  | design
2  | lua
3  | admin
4  | super admin
5  | customer service
```

product table

```
id | role | read | write
1  |  1   |  1   |   0
1  |  2   |  1   |   1
1  |  3   |  0   |   0
1  |  4   |  1   |   1
```

Looking to write a sql query that would get me this record set when i query for `product id = 1`

```
  role_name       | read | write
    design          |   1  |  0
    lua             |   1  |  1
    admin           |   0  |  0
    super admin     |   1  |  1
    customer service|   0  |  0
```

and this one when inserting a new product record, the user will have to define the permission when record is created

```
role_name       | read | write
design          |   0  |  0
lua             |   0  |  0
admin           |   0  |  0
super admin     |   0  |  0
customer service|   0  |  0
```

UPDATE:
This is the statement i tried based on suggested answers

```
select a.name, b.read_allowed,b.write_allowed
from groups a
inner JOIN department_groups r 
    on  a.id = r.groups_id  AND r.department_id=1234
left JOIN department_groups_rel c 
    on a.id = c.groups_id
left  join access_matrix b 
    on c.access_matirx_id = b.id 
group by a.id;
```

I get all the roles from the groups table, but don't get the read and write allowed property set for the specific department

Comment: ok, what have you tried?

Comment: I didnt understand your second question

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` to get roles even if no entry in `product` exists

```
select r.role_name, 
       case when p.read is null then 0 else p.read end as read, 
       case when p.write is null then 0 else p.write end as write
from roles r
left join product p on r.id = p.role
                   and p.id = 1
```

And use a `case` to replace the `nulls` with `0`

Comment: If I add `WHERE p.id = 1` i don't get the roles that are not defined for `p.id=1` i.e i don't get `r.id=5 ` in my resultset

Comment: Because adding conditions of a joined table will turn your `left join` into an `inner join`. Add the condition in the `on` clause. I updated the answer

Comment: jurgen d: used your suggestion to build my query. Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
To get your first preferred result. Try this

SELECT
    roles.role_name, product.read, product.write
FROM
    roles LEFT JOIN product
    ON roles.id = product.role
```